# MongoDB $nin certain fields of embedded document

Tags: mongodb

If I my schema has an embedded document like so:

```
location: {
    coordinates: [-41.588221, 71.123812],
    unitNumber: '4a',
    streetAddress: '1 Abc Lane',
    <Other location-related data>
}
```

And I want to exclude that document and others on the basis of location using `$nin`, but I only have the `unitNumber` and `coordinates`, is there a way to properly do this.

For example, say I want to exclude the following array of locations from a results set:

```
locations = [
    {coordinates: [-41.2342432, 71.812312], unit: '4a'},
    {coordinates: [-40.2242432, 70.212352], unit: '7d'},
    {coordinates: [-42.2546432, 72.312312], unit: '10b'},
    {coordinates: [-41.2342132, 61.812312], unit: '1z'}
]
```

Is there a way to do this given the above schema? I don't believe using `{location: {$nin: locations}}` would work because it would require each object in `locations` to have the entire embedded document to qualify for exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to exclude the documents that match certain `location` and `unit` pairs.

- Compose a condition object which matches all the documents that we
  need to exclude.
- This is done using the [**$all**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator for the `coordinates` field.
- Use the logical [**$nor**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) operator to exclude the matching documents.

Avoid using the [**$nin**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator wherever possible to [optimize](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/) your query.

The query composition needs to be done in the client side,

```
var locationsToExclude= [ {coordinates: [-41.2342432, 71.812312], unit: '4a'}, 
                          {coordinates: [-40.2242432, 70.212352], unit: '7d'},
                          {coordinates: [-42.2546432, 72.312312], unit: '10b'},
                          {coordinates: [-41.2342132, 61.812312], unit: '1z'} 
                        ]

var findCondition = {$nor:[]};
locationsToExclude.forEach(function(i){
    var coordinates = i.coordinates;
    var unitNumber = i.unit;
    var condition = {"coordinates":{$all:coordinates},
                     "unitNumber":unitNumber};
    findCondition.$nor.push(condition);
})
db.location.find(findCondition);
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks! was also worried about performance with `$nin` so I'm glad this was the solution :)

Comment: Hey :) kindly check out this 'kind of similar' [mongodb question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670212/mongodb-how-to-insert-an-embedded-document-in-an-array-if-a-certain-field-is-u). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` to project the location with only coordinates and unit, do a match condition with `$nin` and project again to get the original document using data from $$ROOT:

```
db.location.aggregate([   
     {$group : { _id : "$location", data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }}},
     {$project: { _id: { coordinates: "$_id.coordinates", unit: "$_id.unitNumber" }, data : 1}}, 
     {$match : {_id : {$nin : [
          {coordinates: [-41.2342432, 71.812312], unit: '4a'}, 
          {coordinates: [-40.2242432, 70.212352], unit: '7d'}, 
          {coordinates: [-42.2546432, 72.312312], unit: '10b'}, 
          {coordinates: [-41.2342132, 61.812312], unit: '1z'} ]
     }}},
     {$unwind: "$data"},
     {$project: {_id: 0, location: "$data.location"}}
]);
```

In the last $project, add more fields that you need to get from the original document (data), e.g., `field1: "$data.field1", field2: "$data.field2"`